# Magento 2.2.5: 'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: magento-2.2.5

When i'm trying to use this command:

```
rm -rf var/cache/
```

It throws an error message:  `'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command`.

Comment: you have  using window system  . where  `rm -rf ` linux command

Comment: Its only works on linux you mean? I'm using window 10

Comment: So i guess i've to delete all of it by my hand :(
delete var, generate, pub/static ..

Comment: Alternatively you can install the "Git Bash" and use/access the code as Linux and run most of commands like "rm".

Comment: Yes,  using gitbash you can do but during installation of git bash , you have to select  linux with window option

Comment: nice, its works, thanks a lot you guys :)